# Calender in java returning the same date when changing the time zone?

Tags: java, datetime

I am working on a project where I have to manipulate the dates. Here is the  code snipper I have
My time zone is IST and the conversion time zone is CST.

```
public class Sample {
public static Long time = 1418187600l;
public static TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central");


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(c1.getTime()); // output1 
    c1.setTimeInMillis(time*1000);
    System.out.println(c1.getTime());//output 2
    System.out.println(c1.get(Calendar.DATE));
    c1.setTimeZone(tz1);;
    System.out.println(c1.getTime()); //output 3
    System.out.println(c1.get(Calendar.DATE));
}
```

}

When I ran the program, I got

```
Wed Dec 10 13:03:42 IST 2014
```

for line which was correct.

Then set the time to 1418187600, this output was also correct.

```
Wed Dec 10 10:30:00 IST 2014
```

However when the set the timezone to CST, and tried outputting the date, it returned the same

```
Wed Dec 10 10:30:00 IST 2014
```

while it should have returned **Dec 09 2014 23:00:00**.

However when I tried Calendar.data, it showed the correct date. can anyone explain to me why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

You're printing out a `java.util.Date` (the result of calling `getTime()`). A `Date` doesn't include time zone information at all - `Date.toString()` *always* displays the point in time represented by that `Date` in the default time zone.

Basically, you should avoid calling `Date.toString()` - it's the cause of much confusion. Use a `SimpleDateFormat` instead, which you can set to use a particular time zone.

Alternatively, use the `java.time` classes if you're using Java 8, or [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) otherwise - both are *much* better options than `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: but it seems that doing c1.get(Calendar.DATE) is reliable. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dude: Yes, if you just want the day of month. It's not that `Calendar` and `Date` don't work - it's that their APIs are painful to use.